# error: unable to connect to system d-bus : d-bus not installed

Tags: docker, virtualbox

I am now using Virtual Box to start VM, and the Version is 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2), But when I trying to start the VM, I saw the error msg below:

```
00:00:29.246866 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.000071 main     Log opened 2017-09-06T09:15:08.889100000Z
00:00:29.248469 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.001614 main     OS Product:Linux
00:00:29.248506 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.001654 main     OS Release: 4.4.84-boot2docker
00:00:29.248534 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.001684 main     OS Version: #1 SMP Tue Aug 29 23:44:06 UTC 2017
00:00:29.248561 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.001710 main     Executable: /sbin/VBoxService
00:00:29.248568 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.001711 main     Process ID: 1371
00:00:29.248572 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.001712 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:29.252522 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.005712 main     5.1.26 r117224 started. Verbose level = 0
00:00:29.256154 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.009377 vminfo   rtldrNativeLoad: dlopen('libdbus-1.so.3', RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL) failed: libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
00:00:29.256200 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.009429 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (1/3): D-Bus not installed
00:00:29.260498 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:00:29.274142 NAT: IPv6 not supported
00:00:31.212453 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:31.212606 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:34.254495 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:05.010198 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (2/3): D-Bus not installed
00:00:39.253672 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:10.011849 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (3/3): D-Bus not installed
```

Anyone can help solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I am facing same issue, not able to resolve with following answer. Did u resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

try:
Open Oracle VM VirtualBox and right-click the machine named 'default'. If it is running, select "Close -> Power off". Then select "Remove ..." and hit "Delete all files" button.

close Oracle VM VirtualBox and run Docker_Quickstart again. It will create a new default VM with no permission problems

ref: https://superuser.com/questions/996785/docker-toolbox-error-creating-machine-error-in-driver-during-machine-creation