# Docker Installation Issue on Windows 8

Tags: docker, windows-8, docker-toolbox

I am trying to install docker using DockerToolBox and followed steps from [ToolBox_Install_windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) but I am getting this error:

```
00:00:51.238278 Guest Control: GUEST_MSG_REPORT_FEATURES: 0x1, 0x8000000000000000 
00:00:51.245031 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.019443 vminfo   rtldrNativeLoad: dlopen('libdbus-1.so.3', RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL) failed: libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
00:00:51.245165 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.019599 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (1/3): D-Bus not installed 
00:00:51.253561 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no 
00:00:56.243987 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:05.021831 vminfo Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (2/3): D-Bus not installed
```

And Docker Quickstart Terminal stops with message: `Waiting for an IP...`

Here are some details:
DockerToolbox-19.03.1 
VirtualBox-6.1.12-139181-Win

I also enabled virtualisation in BIOS.

Here are some things I tried but no luck:

1. Close/stop running default VM created in Oracle VM VirtualBox manager
2. Manually start it and close again with option `Send the shutdown signal`
3. Run Docker Quickstart Terminal again.

Same question asked previously [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071615/error-unable-to-connect-to-system-d-bus-d-bus-not-installed) but provided answer is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This same problem was faced by me. What I did
Step 1 uninstall the toolbox
Step 2 download a .exe file
Step 3 normally install it.
https://youtu.be/ntBCU7cZJ1I
Step4 restarted the system
Step 5 clicked on docker toolbox and let it wait.
The point where the it looks for ip address took a long time. And I waited patiently this time
And finally it worked